# Change the binding dynamically in a dialog sapui5

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I have a fragment in which I bind the items to `Voitures` entity But I want to change the binding items to another entity in my model:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m">
 <SelectDialog  title="{i18n>titreVoiture}" search="ChercherVoiture" confirm="fermerdialog"
    cancel="fermerdialog" items="{VoitureModel>/GrosVoitures}">
    <StandardListItem title="{VoitureModel>NomVoiture}" type="Active"/>
  </SelectDialog>
 </core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I want to change the binding from `items={VoitureModel>/GrosVoitures}` to `{VoitureModel>/petitsVoitures}` in controller, I tried this but didn't work

```
if(cPetit === true )
 this.dialog.updateBindingContext(new 
 sap.ui.model.Context(this.getModel('VoitureModel'),
                "/petitsVoitures"));
```

Can you please help ?

Comment: If you want to set the binding inside a controller, use method [bindAggregation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindAggregation) from class sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.

Comment: @fabiopagoti  not just set binding inside a controller i wrote it is a dialog which is binded with a set and i want to change it so if you can detail more i would be thankful

Comment: So kindly provide your model formats. It's not clear what is the format of "petitsVoitures"

Comment: Both entities has the **same properties**? Kindly share the properties of both entities. As you said you want to change the **binding path**, it means that both the entities have the same properties in it. Is it right?

Comment: @inizio    yes they are the same acctualy i am finding difficulty to find the container of the items to change its binding when dubuging

Comment: Then you can just use the common model for binding. When ever you want to change the entity just update the model content, means replace the items inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you, its not the perfect solution but its works. If anyone has a better solution kindly share with us.

You can use single model to bind the items, let say `oModel`. As you said you have `VoitureModel` model with has two properties `GrosVoitures` and `petitsVoitures` which has array of objects. So you can just push all the items inside `GrosVoitures` to `oModel` and when ever you want to change it just update the `oModel` by updating the same model by pushing all the items of `petitsVoitures` to `oModel`.

**Updated XML**

```
<SelectDialog  title="{i18n>titreVoiture}" search="ChercherVoiture" confirm="fermerdialog"
    cancel="fermerdialog" items="{oModel>/items}">
    <StandardListItem title="{oModel>NomVoiture}" type="Active"/>
</SelectDialog>
```

**Controller**

Create default model: **oModel**

`var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();`

You have a model `VoitureModel` and `VoitureModel.getData()` will return

```
{
    "GrosVoitures": [{
        "Id": 0,
        "Name": "AbsenceUI5",
        "OperatingSystemName": "Web",
        "StoreId": "12345",
        "Version": "1"
    }, {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "BPOverview",
        "OperatingSystemName": "Web",
        "StoreId": "12345",
        "Version": "1"
    }],
    "petitsVoitures": [{
        "Id": 0,
        "Name": "AbsenceUI5",
        "OperatingSystemName": "Web",
        "StoreId": "12345",
        "Version": "1"
    }, {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "BPOverview",
        "OperatingSystemName": "Web",
        "StoreId": "12345",
        "Version": "1"
    }]
}
```

So you need to bind `oModel` after setting data using `setData()` of model.

```
var oData = VoitureModel.getData().GrosVoitures; //Return list of objects
oModel.setData({items : [oData] });
```

Now when you want to update the model do the same thing

```
var oData = VoitureModel.getData().petitsVoitures; //Return list of objects
oModel.setData({items : [oData] });
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking time and answering me it means alot :D may god bless you

Comment: Glad it help you :)